# run multiple expect instances through a shell script in background to collect logs

Tags: shell, expect

I'm trying to run multiple expect instances using a shell script in the background, but what actually happens is that the expect processes are killed when the shell script terminates even after running the shell script and expect scripts in the background. Below are the two scripts -

Shell script - shell_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "shell script"

expect expect_script.sh abc1.com user_id password >> /var/logs/abc1.log &
sleep 5
expect expect_script.sh abc2.com user_id password >> /var/logs/abc1.log &
```

Expect script - expect_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]

spawn telnet $ip

expect "User Access Verification"
expect "Username:"
send "$user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";

expect eof
```

This is how I execute -

sh shell_script.sh &

The whole purpose of this script is to run the expect scripts in the background that would collect logs until the processes are killed. Other alternative is to run each expect script one after the other, but to automate and to accommodate near future requests, these expect scripts have to run using a shell script.

Am not an expert in this matter and any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Sirish.

Comment: So you telnet into a device and then wait for eof. How long does an idle telnet session remain alive before the connection is closed?

Comment: Well, this telnet session never closes until the process is killed and that's how the hosts are configured. These hosts send data through the telnet port that should be captured using the expect script to a log file.. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Hands on deck. I tried several ways to execute a shell script that logs the telnet output in the background, but later found the options are not possible because -

1> When you try to execute a child script / command in a master script, even as a background process (using & at the end of the command), the child process will be terminated the moment the master script exits / terminates.

2> You may try to execute the master script forever or in an infinite loop (bad option :P), but the telnet session or channel cannot run as a background process as the OS kills the channel associated to the telnet session. I don't have much details regarding this but this is one of the output from my experiments.

Now comes the solution.. After banging my head and breaking walls around my cube, this is how I made it work -

Using screen command to create a session that would run just as a user login session and below is a working copy of my script -

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dmS "abc-alpha-32"
sleep 2
echo 'running script command in session..'
screen -S abc-alpha-32 -p abc-alpha-32 -X stuff "script -f /home/user12/scripts/abc-alpha-32.log $(printf \\r)"
sleep 2
echo 'running expect command in session..'
screen -S abc-alpha-32 -p abc-alpha-32 -X stuff "expect /home/user12/scripts/master_dian.sh abc-alpha-32.cisco.com user_id password $(printf \\r)"
```

** NOTE: Arguments '-p abc-alpha-32' (in above screen command) is mandatory to tell the screen command to which screen you were to send the command.

master_dian.sh -

This script has all those commands to substitute user id and password using expect. Below is a working copy -

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hostName [lindex $argv 0] 
set userName [lindex $argv 1] 
set password [lindex $argv 2] 

spawn telnet $hostName

expect "User Access Verification"
expect "Username:"
send "$userName\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

and that's it. These telnet sessions run in the background in a new session and each session will create a log file using the "script -f" command and the data is in the log file.

Thank you for ones who helped me out and for their time.

Appreciated and good day.!